# Check string and file empty in script shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have the script below that makes a query for the String `ERROR` generated by **HTTP** queries, I would like it to check all lines and just return me `TRUE` for when there is an error or file is empty

**result.log**

```
Collecting: LINK1 HTTP 200
EXCEPT ERROR - REST API LINK2 returned HTTP Error
```

**Script:**

```
  1 cat /healthcheck/bin/gaps/result.log | grep HTTP | while read line
  2 do
  3     echo "$line" | grep "ERROR" >/dev/null
  4     if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  5         RESULT = "TRUE"
  6     fi
  7 done
  8
  9 echo $RESULT
```

**Output:**

```
./check.sh: line 5: RESULT: command not found
./check.sh: line 5: RESULT: command not found
```

**Shell check:**

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
cat /healthcheck/bin/gaps/result.log | grep HTTP | while read line
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.
    ^-- SC2002: Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.
                                                         ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

Line 4:
     if [ $? = 0 ]; then
          ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.

Line 5:
         RESULT = "TRUE"
         ^-- SC2030: Modification of RESULT is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).
                ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments (or quote to make it literal).

Line 9:
echo $RESULT
     ^-- SC2031: RESULT was modified in a subshell. That change might be lost.

$
```

Comment: done, I'm a shell starter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe runs in a subshell. Changes from a subshell are not visible to parent shell. The site [bashfaq/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) presents possible workarounds.

You can put break the line if `|` is the last character on the line, no need to build super long lines for pipelines.

Upper case variables are by convention reserved for exported variables.

`cat ... | grep` is a useless use of `cat.` Just `grep ...` or `< file grep`.

When you check command return value, just `if the command; then` instead of `the command; if [ $? ...`.

Use `grep`s exit status in an `if`. In bash just `if <<<"$string" grep -q "pattern"; then`. In posix shell do `if printf "%s\n" "$string" | grep -q "pattern"; then`.

Bash is space aware. The `RESULT = "TRUE"` *executes a command named `RESULT`* with two arguments. It's `RESULT="TRUE"`

Use `while IFS= read -r line` to read the whole line exactly.

So while you could:

```
cat /healthcheck/bin/gaps/result.log |
grep HTTP |
{
  while read line
  do
      echo "$line" | grep "ERROR" >/dev/null
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         RESULT="TRUE"
      fi
  done
  echo $RESULT
}
```

In your case, it's just:

```
if grep "HTTP" /healthcheck/bin/gaps/result.log | grep -q "ERROR"; then
   echo TRUE
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and sorry for the silly mistakes, I am still learning shell, just a question with echo in the end will it display TRUE for each line that exists for stirng ERROR?

Comment: Both code snippets as presented will print the string `TRUE` only once.